# How can I configure the RethinkDB service on OSX to use a certain configuration file?

Tags: macos, homebrew, rethinkdb

I install RethinkDB on OS X through homebrew as per [the official instructions](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/osx/). However, I need for the RethinkDB daemon to use a certain configuration file.

The [official RethinkDB docs](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/start-on-startup/) say to modify the .plist file installed by homebrew, so that the `--config-file` option to the rethinkdb daemon is used:

`<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/rethinkdb</string>
    <string>--config-file</string>
    <string>/etc/rethinkdb.conf</string>
</array>`

The drawback to this method however, is that your changes will be overwritten upon next upgrade of the RethinkDB installation.

Is there some safe way to make the rethinkdb daemon use a configuration file, which is persisted across upgrades of RethinkDB?

Comment: If you change the permissions of the `.plist` to root user then I would imagine that homebrew shouldn't be allowed to overwrite it, unless of course you are using homebrew as root.

Comment: That sounds way too dirty imo.

Comment: I completely agree, although I find it really odd that an upgrade would completely overwrite your configuration too. Maybe locking the file or chflags might suffice rather than setting the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two different options here:

1. Rather than trying to fight `homebrew`, use their configuration location, which defaults to `/usr/local/etc/rethinkdb.conf` (depends on your `home-brew` config). I don't think that they change the config file on updates, and my limited testing seems to back that up.
2. Don't use `homebrew`s launchd plist, but rather create your own in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`. I dislike `homebrew`s anyways since you wind up symlinking it from `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, so it only runs when your user is logged in. That works for single-user systems, but rankles me as a sysadmin a bit. This solution is a bit of an odd duck, since you would be running a user-owned binary as root... but if you are using `homebrew` for this you are already in similar waters.

If it was me, I would skip `homebrew` altogether, and just use the .pkg available on the website (full disclosure: I work on that .pkg). The docs that you linked to include how to setup a `launchd` plist for that, and since the .pkg does not include that, you don't have to worry about that messing with your configuration.

Comment: I don't completely understand option 1. From my recollection, the brew-installed .plist doesn't supply the `--config-file` option to rethinkdb, so how can it default to /usr/local/etc/rethinkdb.conf?

Comment: Nevermind, I see now that they do supply the `--config-file` option! Did this recently change? I'm pretty sure it wasn't like this before, as I was forced to edit the .plist.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the .plist file in ~/Library/LaunchAgent is usually a symlink to the real one in the homebrew system f.ex. `/usr/local/Cellar/rethinkdb/2.1.5-2/homebrew.mxcl.rethinkdb.plist`. Furthermore, .plist files rarely change. Therefore, we can safely copy the original .plist file somewhere, and load that instead.

So, instead of symlinking, you can manually copy the file to ~/Library/LaunchAgent, and modify it. Homebrew won't change the file in `~/Library/LaunchAgent`. When upgrading, it will only change the file beneath `/usr/local/Cellar`.